# Cannot receive DHCP OFFER on ethernet

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet, dhcp, wired

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

I have exactly the same issue as described in [this question on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/435751/cannot-receive-dhcp-offer); my laptop's ethernet/wired cannot receive DHCP offer.

1. I can verify it's not a network/server issue, as it works in live cd. Other laptop works fine using the same cable, so definitely not [an issue with a cable](https://askubuntu.com/a/730845/517280).
2. My laptop ethernet doesn't work at my home nor my friend's place.
3. I tried the `rfc` and `identifier` workarounds mentioned by this [Ubuntu Forums thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1156441), but to no avail.
4. I tried disabling ufw/gufw firewall, no avail.
5. `dhclient <iface_name>` simply times out. When a static IP is used, NetworkManager shows it's connected, but I can't ping anywhere.
6. I tried clearing `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`, to no avail.
7. I tried `r8168-dkms` driver, to no avail.
8. I tried all options of link negotiation, to no avail.
9. <s>I'm using kernel 4.15.0-29.31, I tried booting older kernel 4.15.0-23.25, no avail.</s> Cold boot (without restart) 4.15.0-23.25 or 4.15.0-20 through GRUB advanced options resolve my issue.
10. No issue on wifi.

This is the second time this has happened to me. Previously I simply gave up and reformated/reinstalled. Ethernet was previously functional again from fresh install until now (2 months later).

I'm trying to avoid doing a fresh install this time as this probably will happen again if the (currently unknown) cause is not addressed.

NetworkManager log:

```
device (enp3s0f1): carrier: link connected
device (enp3s0f1): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
manager: startup complete
device (enp3s0f1): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' ()
audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="" name="Wired connection 1" pid= uid= result="success"
device (enp3s0f1): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
device (enp3s0f1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
device (enp3s0f1): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
dhcp4 (enp3s0f1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
dhcp4 (enp3s0f1): dhclient started with pid 
device (enp3s0f1): carrier: link connected
dhcp4 (enp3s0f1): request timed out
dhcp4 (enp3s0f1): state changed unknown -> timeout
dhcp4 (enp3s0f1): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 
dhcp4 (enp3s0f1): state changed timeout -> done
device (enp3s0f1): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
device (enp3s0f1): Activation: failed for connection 'Wired connection 1'
device (enp3s0f1): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
device (enp3s0f1): state change: disconnected -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
device (enp3s0f1): carrier: link connected
device (enp3s0f1): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

dhclient log:

```
dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'dhclient'
dhcp4 (enp3s0f1): dhclient started with pid 
DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x48f58660)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5 (xid=0x48f58660)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0x48f58660)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x48f58660)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x48f58660)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp3s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0x48f58660)
```

```
$ lspci | grep Ethernet
03:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
```

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 73
       serial: 
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-29-generic firmware=17.948900127.0 ip=10.233.9.0 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:47 memory:e3500000-e3501fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.1
       logical name: enp3s0f1
       version: 12
       serial: 
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:19 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:e3404000-e3404fff memory:e3400000-e3403fff
```

```
$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

Edit: Looks similar to [Unable to activate the ethernet connection after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034194/unable-to-activate-the-ethernet-connection-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-18-04). User resolved it with recent update. But in this case, recent update could have *broken* it instead.

Edit2: `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` is missing, but wifi works.

Edit3: Just tried a USB ethernet (Dell Docking D3100), it works. So, this is an issue of my laptop realtek built-in nic.

Comment: I have the same problem. I suspect that the network interface is silently dropping some packets. Evidence: In my case, I ran tcpdump on the client, which makes the network interface promiscuous, using `sudo tcpdump -n udp port 68 -vv`, and the connection succeeds when I connect the ethernet cable to the network. Contrast with `sudo tcpdump -n udp port 68 --no-promiscuous-mode -vv` where the connection does not succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My latest kernel installed is 4.15.0-29. Cold booting older kernel 4.15.0-23 or 4.15.0-20 resolved my issue.

Similar kernel issues reported:

- [Kernels 4.15.0-29 through -36 caused top panel network options to disappear. 18.04 16.xx](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058244/software-update-to-kernel-4-15-0-29-caused-top-panel-network-options-to-disappea)
- [Updated to 4.15.0-29.31 Ubuntu 18.04, and my wifi and ethernet stopped working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058284/updated-to-4-15-0-29-31-ubuntu-18-04-and-my-wifi-and-ethernet-stopped-working)
- [Wireless adapter stopped working after kernel update to 4.15](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058650/wireless-adapter-stopped-working-after-kernel-update-to-4-15)
- [[kubuntu] No login screen after 4.15.0-29 kernel upgrade](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/%5Bkubuntu%5D-no-login-screen-after-4-15-0-29-kernel-upgrade-4175634708/#post5882541)

How do I submit a kernel bug report? Which logs should I attach?

Edit: Submitted a bug report [#1784542](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1784542).

Edit2: `canonical-livepatch` has to be disabled after booting older kernel to avoid issue with `compiz`.

Edit3: Maybe related to Spectre mitigation (see [this article](https://news.softpedia.com/news/canonical-fixes-boot-failures-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-and-16-04-4-lts-update-now-522073.shtml)).

Edit4: There is [a working fix](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1784542/comments/11) to be backported.

Edit5: [Fix released](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1784542/comments/14) in kernel 4.15.0-33.36. This issue came back when I first enabled `canonical-livepatch`, but a reboot resolved it.

Comment: Run `ubuntu-bug linux` that will create a bug report.