# Bluetooth Not Working on Kubuntu 19.04?

Tags: kubuntu, bluetooth, services, 19.04

I'm experiencing issues with my laptop's internal bluetooth adapter. It lost the connection to my wireless mouse a few times, and then lost the mouse entirely.

When I used `sudo service bluetooth restart`, it just disappeared entirely, and now no longer even appears in the system tray.

I'm not sure how to get it back so I can pair to other devices.

[image: System Tray]

**EDIT 0:** Also when I'm in the bluetooth GUI manager it says that my bluetooth adapter is not powered. I'll post more when I get back home.
[image: Not Powered]

**EDIT 1:** Upon restarting, bluetooth works again, but it still has this strange stutter issue. My mouse is connected via bluetooth, but about every minute it seemingly loses the signal and I can move the mouse and nothing will happen on the screen. Then the mouse will move the way it was supposed to but with only after 5 seconds, sometimes longer. Then it's fine until it does it again in the next minute.

**EDIT 2: Computer Information:**

```
sarah@LesserArk:~$ sudo lshw -C network 
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: bb
       serial: e4:70:b8:f8:99:b8
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.18-041518-generic firmware=17.3216344376.0 ip=192.168.1.128 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:31 memory:d3600000-d3601fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0f:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 0c
       serial: a0:1d:48:fa:67:c0
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:27 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:d3500000-d3500fff memory:d3400000-d3403fff
```

And I'm using an HP ENVY 17.

Comment: What does `uname -r` reveal in the kernel?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix It's a fresh install, but I ran it anyway: `5.0.0-13-generic`

Comment: Try an older kernel: https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade/885165#885165 I can vouch for `4.14.110` but there are many to choose from.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix That's a good point. I didn't think that the kernel upgrade might have done it. Is there something wrong with the kernel? Can I file something like a big report or is that just how it is? I'll try it later.

Comment: All I can say is no problems for me with Kernel `4.14.110`. Try that version to see if things work. The other thing is we need to know your computer and wifi model numbers.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I posted the wi-fi/bluetooth card. I'm using kernel `4.15.18-041518-generic`. No problems yet, I'll test the Bluetooth later.

Comment: I use infrared mouse and keyboard so don't have any problems. But here is a complicated answer that may help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090149/bluetooth-mouse-lags-after-upgrading-to-18-10-cosmic

Comment: Have you filled a launchpad bug for this? I've just ran into a very similar situation(Kubuntu 19.04, bluetooth mouse suddenly stopped working and the bluetooth adapter suddenly stopped being detected) and wouldn't want to duplicate reports.